# sending Firebase value to text fields

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, uitextfield

I have a view controller with three text fields. When the user uses the app for the first time, they enter some information in those text fields and press done, then the information goes to Firebase database:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).setValue(saveObject)
```

However, the user also has the ability to edit those three text fields. As of now, when the user edits one text field and clicks done. The information of the non-edited text fields appear in their own text fields and then the user has to click the done button again for the edited text field to be sent to Firebase:

```
 if City.text==""
            {
                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


                    if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {


                        let city = postsDictionary["City"] as? String ?? ""
                        self.City.text = city
                    }})

            }
            if Major.text==""
            {
                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


                    if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {


                        let major = postsDictionary["Major"] as? String ?? ""
                        self.Major.text = major
                    }})

            }
            if College.text==""
            {
                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


                    if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {


                        let college = postsDictionary["College"] as? String ?? ""
                        self.College.text = college
                    }})

            }
            if College.text=="" || Major.text=="" || City.text==""
            {
                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

                    })

            }else{


            if let City = City.text{
                if let Major = Major.text{
                    if let College = College.text{

                        let saveObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                            "uid": uid,
                            "City" : City,
                            "Major" : Major,
                            "College" : College
                        ]
                        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).setValue(saveObject)
```

I don't think this is very user-friendly, I would like the user to edit whatever text field they want and I do not want the non-edited text field values to appear in their text fields and I would like the user to click on the done button once for the newly edited text field value to be sent to firebase.

Comment: Yes so when a new user puts in information in the three text fields for the first time it goes the firebase. If the user decides to edit just one or two text fields then only those text fields should be changed in firebase and the non-edited one should remain the same in firebase @AaronZheng

Comment: @AaronZheng Thank you very much

Comment: If the city field is empty (not edited), I didn't want it replacing the already existing value in firebase with an empty value

Comment: @AaronZheng yes

Comment: @AaronZheng what past comments? Yes it works. When I edit a text field and click done, the text fields that were not edited gets updated with the values in firebase and then I have to click done a second time for the text field that was edited to get updated in firebase. I would at least like to click done once for the edited text field to be sent to firebase

Comment: I don't want the users to click the done button twice in order for the edited text field to be updated in firebase @AaronZheng

Comment: Why would the user click twice?

Comment: Thats what it is doing right now, and I am trying to solve it. The first click the non-edited text fields (empty) and updated with the information from firebase (not empty anymore) and on the second click, the edited text field is sent to firebase @AaronZheng

Comment: ok gave you the answer, let me know if you are confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create this func in viewdidload. This will load your current properties in firebase. You should adopt the UITextFieldDelegate and add the function textDidBegin which then you can make the textField (sender as! textField class) blank instead of having these loaded properties.

```
        func reloadFirDatabase() 
        {  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


                          if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                        let city = postsDictionary["City"] as? String ?? ""
                                        let major = postsDictionary["Major"] as? String ?? ""
                                        let college = postsDictionary["College"] as? String ?? ""
                         if City.text.isEmpty {
                                    self.City.text = city    
                         {
                         if Major.text.isEmpty {
                                    self.Major.text = major
                         }
                         if College.text.isEmpty {
                                    self.College.text = college
                         } 


                                    }})
            }
```

When you press done you should still load this in:

```
if let City = City.text{
                if let Major = Major.text{
                    if let College = College.text{

                        let saveObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                            "uid": uid,
                            "City" : City,
                            "Major" : Major,
                            "College" : College
                        ]
                        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).setValue(saveObject)
```

I can guarantee you that doing it this way you only need to press the done button once.

Comment: If you have any doubts or are confused in any part, let me know.

Comment: works even better than I wanted it to!! Thank you!! so so much!!

Comment: Hey Aaron, you really helped me out a lot! I have been having troubles with some code for weeks and I was wondering if you could check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658759/custom-multiple-uiimagepicker-using-firebase/44658973#44658973 Thank you so much it would be deeply appreciated