# animated button in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom expandable table view. The expanded tableViewCell has a button in it that contain some animations. So when the tableViewCell is expanded:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell
    if isExpanded && self.selectedIndex == indexPath {
                cell.CustomView.frame = CGRect(x: 7, y: 8, width: 359, height: 283)
            }
           else {
           cell.CustomView.frame = CGRect(x: 7, y: 8, width: 359, height: 115)

            }}
```

You can see more details of the cell. At the bottom of the expanded cell, there is a button. And when you click on the button three more buttons appear:

```
@IBAction func UserAddClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        if UserAdd.currentImage == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-Plus-48"){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

                self.UserShare.alpha = 1
                self.UserEdit.alpha = 1
                self.UserDelete.alpha = 1

            })
        }else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

                self.UserShare.alpha = 0
                self.UserEdit.alpha = 0
                self.UserDelete.alpha = 0

            })
        }
        toggleButton(button: sender as! UIButton, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-Plus-48"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "AddOn"))
    }
```

when I click on the cell, it should return back to its original non-expanded cell height. My issue is when I click on the cell to return to it's non-expanded cell height, I also want the three buttons to disappear. So that if I click the cell a third time, at the bottom of the cell I should only see one button. But when I click the cell a third time to expand it, I still see the four buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to answer this question the best I can. Just change your selected table view cell code to this :

```
if isExpanded && self.selectedIndex == indexPath {
            cell.CustomView.frame = CGRect(x: 7, y: 8, width: 359, height: 283)

                self.UserShare.alpha = 0
                self.UserEdit.alpha = 0
                self.UserDelete.alpha = 0


        }
       else {
       cell.CustomView.frame = CGRect(x: 7, y: 8, width: 359, height: 115)

        }
```

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: would you possibly know the solution to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600680/sending-firebase-value-to-text-fields

Comment: Let me take a look.