# Custom multiple UIImagePicker using Firebase

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have an image array `var images: NSArray! = []` that collects a max of five images with a custom UIImagePicker. I need to send the images to Firebase, but Firebase does not accept arrays so I turned each index of the array into its own UIImage:

```
let imageOne = images[0] as? UIImage
let imageTwo = images[1] as? UIImage
let imageThree = images[2] as? UIImage
let imageFour = images[3] as? UIImage
let imageFive = images[4] as? UIImage
```

Then I created a function to send the images to firebase:

```
func uploadImage(image: UIImage){
    var randomName = randomStringWithLength(length: 5)
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageOne!, 1.0)
    let imageDatas = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageTwo!, 1.0)
    let imageDataThree = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageThree!, 1.0)
    let imageDataFour = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFour!, 1.0)
    let imageDataFive = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFive!, 1.0)


    let uploadRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(randomName).jpg")
    guard let ImageData = imageData else { return }
    uploadRef.put(ImageData, metadata: nil) { metadata,
        error in
        if error == nil {
            print("successfully uploaded Image")

            self.imageFileName = "\(randomName as String).jpg"

            randomName = randomStringWithLength(length: 5)


            let uploadRef2 = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(randomName).jpg")
            guard let Imagedatas = imageDatas else { return }
            uploadRef2.put(Imagedatas, metadata: nil) { metadata,
                error in
                if error == nil {
                    self.imageFileNameTwo = "\(randomName as String).jpg"
                } else{
                    print("Error uploading image")
                }
                randomName = randomStringWithLength(length: 5)


                let uploadRef3 = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(randomName).jpg")
                guard let imageDataThrees = imageDataThree else { return }
                uploadRef3.put(imageDataThrees, metadata: nil) { metadata,
                    error in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.imageFileNameThree = "\(randomName as String).jpg"
                    } else{
                        print("Error uploading image")
                    }
                    randomName = randomStringWithLength(length: 5)


                    let uploadRef4 = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(randomName).jpg")
                    guard let imageDataFours = imageDataFour else { return }
                    uploadRef4.put(imageDataFours, metadata: nil) { metadata,
                        error in
                        if error == nil {
                            self.imageFileNameFour = "\(randomName as String).jpg"
                        } else{
                            print("Error uploading image")
                        }

                        randomName = randomStringWithLength(length: 5)


                        let uploadRef5 = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(randomName).jpg")
                        guard let imageDataFives = imageDataFive else { return }
                        uploadRef5.put(imageDataFives, metadata: nil) { metadata,
                            error in
                            if error == nil {
                                AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicator()
                                self.imageFileNameFive = "\(randomName as String).jpg"
                            } else{
                                print("Error uploading image")
                            }

            let postObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [

                "image" : self.imageFileName,
                "imageTwo" : self.imageFileNameTwo,
                "imageThree" : self.imageFileNameThree,
                "imageFour" : self.imageFileNameFour,
                "imageFive" : self.imageFileNameFive,


            ]

            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).child(key).setValue(postObject)
          }}}}} else{
            print("Error uploading image")

        }}



}


if let pickedImageFirst = imageOne,
let pickedImageSecond = imageTwo,
let pickedImageThird = imageThree,
let pickedImageFour = imageFour,
let pickedImageFive = imageFive {
uploadImage(image: pickedImageFirst)
```

This function requires the user to always 5 images otherwise it crashes. However, I want it to be optional. So that a user can select between one or five images. Right now if I select less than 5 images, I get this crash:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'**

Answer (score 0):

You could use `guard` statements instead of force unwrapping all you images in one place.

```
guard let imageData = imageData else { return }
uploadRef.put(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata,
    error in
    if error == nil {
        print("successfully uploaded Image")

        self.imageFileName = "\(randomName as String).jpg"

        randomName = randomStringWithLength(length: 5)
        let uploadRef2 = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(randomName).jpg")

        guard let imageDatas = imageDatas else { return }
        uploadRef2.put(imageDatas, metadata: nil) { metadata
```

And so on through your function.

Comment: when I do that, I get an error on the guard let imageData = imageData else { return } line "use of unresolved identifier 'imageData'

Comment: You need to provide more code. No one here is a mind reader. The person trying to help you assumed you had defined imageData since you reference it in your code.

Comment: @Mozahler imageData was defined I included it in my original question `let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageOne!, 1.0)`

Comment: @thexande I have been working on this for weeks and I can't seem to find a solution. Please if you can help me. when I do your given solution, it says that I have a redeclaration of imageData but when I remove my `let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageOne!, 1.0)` it says that imageData is not declared

Comment: change the guard let declaration to another name like `guard let image = imageData`

Comment: You need to read more about guards and swift in general. Check out this: https://ericcerney.com/swift-guard-statement/